# The direction of Gradient Filter in openCV

Tags: python, opencv

thanks for taking a look.

The question pops up when I read concepts help on [this website](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/372916L-01/nivisionconcepts/spatial_filtering/)

When applying a gradient convolution filter, with a different given direction, different edges are given depending on light intensity, see following:

[filter result with positive direction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyRkz.png)

[filter result with negative direction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNx5F.png)

Then I tried to implement the same in opencv with `cv2.Sobel` in y axis.

```
cv2.Sobel(img,cv2.CV_8U,0,1)
```

The code only shows detected edges in one direction. I didn't manage to change the direction to show the edge detected with another intensity.

I am aware that with `CV_64`, one can detect both, but I wish to have them separately, exactly same as the example showed previously.

I found a trick to invert b/w of the image `img=255-img`, afterwards applying the same filter `cv2.Sobel(img,cv2.CV_8U,0,1)` cloud show the other edge as I expected.

I was wondering if it is possible just by `cv2.Sobel` function or any other opencv filter to control this filter direction without the need of inverting b/w of image .

Comment: It's convolution, so why not use `filter2D`?

Answer (score 3):

OpenCV lets you apply the Sobel filter only in the y and in the x direction. You can check the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=sobel#cv2.Sobel) to see more info about the kernels applied.

For the x direction it is:

```
cv2.Sobel(img,cv2.CV_8U,1,0)
```

And for the y direction:

```
cv2.Sobel(img,cv2.CV_8U,0,1)
```

This last 2 numbers mean the order of the derivative of the image in x and y respectively. You can have more complicated ones as in both directions at the same time:

```
cv2.Sobel(img,cv2.CV_8U,1,1)
```

Also, I see that in your images you have another operator (diagonal). I am not sure if you can do it with the sobel function directly, but certainly you can do it "manually" using [filter2D](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#cv2.filter2D).

```
cv2.filter2D(img, cv2.CV_8U, kernel)
```

where kernel is your kernel matrix that appears in your image.

```
kernel = np.array([[0, -1, -1],
                   [1,  0, -1],
                   [1,  1,  0]])
```